# When I use Django to develop a blog, the static html page in the form of some problems

Tags: python, django

How can I get back to the index page after I click on the submit button. I wrote some code he can normally return to the index page but there is no content, that some of the title content and the like

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^xadmin/', xadmin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index,),
    url(r'^bbs/', index,),
    url(r'^details/(\d+)/$', get_details),
    url(r'^bbs_pub/$', bbs_pub, name='publish'),
    url(r'^bbs_sub/$', bbs_sub, name='sub'),
]
```

views:

```
def bbs_sub(request):
title = request.POST.get('title')
contet = request.POST.get('content')
author = models.BBSuser.objects.get(username='merinw')
models.BBS.objects.create(
    title=title,
    summary='dsad',
    content=contet,
    author=author,
    view_count = 10
)
return render(request,'index.html',)
```

index.html:

```
<div class="container"style="margin-top: 70px">
{% block page-content %}
    <div class="border">
    <a href="{% url 'publish' %}">
        <div style="margin-right: 30px; ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="false" style="font-size: 40px" ></span>
    </div>
    </a>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    {% for bbs in bbs_list %}
       <h4> <a href="/details/{{ bbs.id }}" >{{ bbs.title }}</a></h4>
        <br>
        {{ bbs.summary }}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

publish.html

```
<form method="post" action="/bbs_sub/" class="editor">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label>文章标题
      <input type="text" name="title" class="title">
  </label>
<textarea id="mytextarea" name="content"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="提交" class="subbtu">
  {% csrf_token %}
```

When I run the end, the index page is empty，who can give me some suggestions。

Answer (score 2):

you have not passed your "bbs_list" while rendering of request,  and you are accessing that in index.html

better way is,  fetch list in view and render to page using context={"bbs_list"=[]}

`return render(request,'index.html',context={"bbs_list"=[]})`

Comment: I realized my mistake, it was stupid, never been found before, thank you for your reminder, I have succeeded, save a lot of time.

Comment: yeah, this small mistakes never get found easily. Be careful